# How to use group by on an outer join in linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join

Please i have my two tables, i recently learnt to outer join the two in linq. My problem now is i want to use group by a particular column for a i want to return a sum as well. Below is how i join the tables.

```
var result = from l1 in repository.Locations
                       join l2 in repository.Rooms on l1.LocationName equals l2.Location
                       into l3
                       from tempLocations in l3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new
                       {
                           l1.LocationName,
                           total = (tempLocations == null ? String.Empty : tempLocations.Location)
                       };
```

My problem is the column total, intend to group by `l1.LocationName` and the `count()` as total. Please any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I want to group by the Location Column and LocationName column from the l1 and l2 tables. I want to return something like.
[image]

The LocationNAme is from Locations Table , LOcation Column is from Rooms Table , i want to outer join the two tables where LocationNAme = Location and count existence of LocationName in Room Table .

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you're applying a left join, all the records from Locations table is coming up, So how you need to group them and you want total of what? Do provide a sample input\ output of sample data you are expecting.

Comment: You can't group by the column l1.LocationName only because you need to group by all the columns you do not aggregate. And as I understand this, these are LocationID, LocationName and Location. Just insert a Group By between the FROM and SELECT-Part and add the Count to your SELECT-List